# Preventing enable/disable of module via .install file

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks

I've written a module that depends on an overridden value in $conf in settings.php. Specifically, it's a custom session handler set in $conf[session_inc]

This override needs to be present for the module to work and definitely needs to not be present when the module is disabled/uninstalled.

Is there anyway to stop the enable/disable process from within the .install file? I need to force users to configure settings.php properly before these actions. The return values of enable/disable hooks are apparently ignored.

I need to prevent users from sawing off the branch their sitting on :)

Comment: See also: [How to deal with module conflicts (“anti-dependencies”)?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/how-to-deal-with-module-conflicts-anti-dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `hook_requirements()` to require the setting before the initial installation (`install`) and during status checks (`runtime`).

Preventing your module from being disabled doesn't seem possible within the .install file. Perhaps, instead, you can check for `module_exists()` in your session handler and route back to the default handler if your module is disabled?

Comment: I don't think module_exists() is available during bootstrapping. There's no way to know what modules are disabled/enabled during that phase AFAIK. About the only solution I can think of is to do a form_alter on the modules page and disable the checkbox for my module if things aren't right. But I can't do that for 'enable' because my module won't be enabled to do the form_alter :)

Comment: I've never used that hook before. It looks like it will be the best way to notify the admin if things are not configured properly. Unfortunately, it won't help on un-install. And in my case, if certain configuration is not restored after un-install, the site 'splodes!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example of preventing module to be enabled based on some variable from settings file:

```
/**
 * Implements requirements().
 */
function hook_devel_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();
  // Ensure translations don't break at install time
  $t = get_t();

  if ($phase == 'install') {
    global $conf;
    if ($conf["my_environment"] == 'live') {
      $requirements['mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => $t('Custom Devel'),
        'value' => $t('This module should not be enabled on Production, sorry!'),
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
      );
    }
  }
  return $requirements;
}
```

It's looking for global `$conf['my_environment']` variable defined in settings file. And if it's set to 'live', it'll preventing the module to be enabled.

Remember to change `hook` and `mymodule` to your appropriate module name. The code should be used in `.install` file.